# Javascript: Prepared statement for a long query

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to defend my game against SQL injection, and I've read using prepared statements is one way to do it, something like this:

```
var userId = 5;
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [userId], function(err, results) {
  //query.sql returns SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '5'
});
```

But how do I do it when my SQL looks like this?

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO ${table} (prefix_id, suffix_id, identifier_index, username, hashbrown, salt, date_created, date_updated) 
                SELECT ${args.prefix_id}, ${args.suffix_id}, COALESCE(MAX(identifier_index) + 1, 1), CONCAT(${args.username}, COALESCE(MAX(identifier_index) + 1, 1)),
                ${args.hash}, ${args.salt}, NOW(), NOW() from ${table} where prefix_id = ${args.prefix_id} AND suffix_id = ${args.suffix_id}`;
```

Now because this is gonna eventually go on to AWS Lambda and API gateway, I'd rather not use some third party node library or something that just might break.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should not build the query on the client-side, just pass the data to the server-side, and build up the query based on the passed (and checked) data. Or is this actually a nodejs question?

Comment: You can't use prepared statements to dynamically bind table names, so pure prepared statements ill not be a solution for you. The big question is: where do all the parameters come from? Btw, prepared statements is a functionality offered by the official MySQL API. node.js MySQL connector just utilises this functionality.

Comment: @Shadow, the table names can be hard coded, if need be. Can prepared statements work?

Comment: Yep, in that case prepared statements can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
const query = connection.query(
    `INSERT INTO ${table} (prefix_id, suffix_id, identifier_index, username, hashbrown, salt, date_created, date_updated) 
            SELECT ?, ?, COALESCE(MAX(identifier_index) + 1, 1), CONCAT(?, COALESCE(MAX(identifier_index) + 1, 1)),
            ?, ?, NOW(), NOW() from ${table} where prefix_id = ? AND suffix_id = ?`,
    [
        args.prefix_id,
        args.suffix_id,
        args.username,
        args.hash,
        args.salt,
        args.prefix_id,
        args.suffix_id
    ],
    function(err,results) {
        //
    }
);
```

?

Comment: And what about the table names?

Comment: If they cannot be passed as parameters as well then maybe you could leave them as expressions in the template literal but check their validity against a predefined list or pattern. Or do you need to be able to handle any table name?

Comment: Had an issue with the ?? - it turned all the escapes into a tilde (`), which didn't sit well with the SQL (it thinks the value is a column). I turned all the ?? in to a ?, and all worked well, though you might want to update your answer.